# Negative masses

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity

If there existed negative masses how would one use Newton's law of gravitation (since it doesn't spit out the direction of the gravitational force but only the magnitude like Coulomb's law)? Would negative masses repel when placed near positive mass (opposite happens for charges)? Even in the derivation of gravitational potential we have used displacement as attractive and negative so would that change for negative masses?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negative Mass and gravitation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34115/)

Comment: Both Newton’s law of gravitation and Coulomb’s law *can* “spit out” the direction of the force. Perhaps you have not yet seen their formulation in terms of vectors.

Comment: Also consider what happens to $\pmb{F}=m\pmb{a}$ if $m<0$.