# Why do there exist negative and positive electric charges but only positive masses?

Tags: charge, mass

Why are there positive and negative charges but only positive masses? The spin-2 nature of gravitons is responsible for the fact that masses with the same sign attract, and the spin-1 nature of photons is responsible for the repulsion of charges with the same sign.

Color charges even show up in three types.

The balance of positive and negative charges is responsible for the overall balance of the EM force, in contrast to the sole presence of positive masses/energy currents, which causes all mass/energy to form lumps that can overcome the EM force, as is vividly demonstrated by black holes.

Is there some deeper reason why negative masses don't exist? Is there some symmetry maybe which causes this?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34115/2451 and links therein.