# Bohr Model of the Hydrogen Atom - Energy Levels of the Hydrogen Atom

Tags: atomic-physics

Q.1) What is the idea of stationary orbital of electron? As it is said energy tangled with mass and vice versa how is this energy always be in the form of cloud such as s, p, d, f? From where does this energy come from?Why don't the energy cloud vanish away or what is stopping it to not vanish away?

Comment: Possible duplicate Have a look at this link http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137207/trouble-understanding-the-bohr-model-of-the-atom?rq=1

Comment: Thanks to notify me that but that person is asking other thing. As you can read in my question that why energy always be in the form of clouds like s, p, etc? Why the energy orbital is not escaping or can say lose out?

Comment: Have you got an answer you are happy with? If not I will try an answer for you if you like today?

Comment: No I didn't got my answer

Comment: In Bohr's model there are nothing like orbitals ,only orbits,you should probably edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all let us make clear the the Bohr model posits orbits, with some imposed by hand quantization constraints, as the stationary assumption.

Orbitals for the hydrogen atom are the solutions of the Schrodinger equation with the hydrogen potential energy and helped develop quantum mechanical theory.

In QM the solution of the schrodinger equation is a wave function and the square of this wave function gives the probability of finding the electron at a specific (x,y,z). Orbitals are probability distributions with specific quantum numbers. The theory and the experiment [agree](http://io9.com/the-first-image-ever-of-a-hydrogen-atoms-orbital-struc-509684901) .

A hydrogen atom in its ground state (n=1,s) will stay there forever unless the atom is hit with a photon with an energy difference between the s state and another orbital position. Thus the energy for higher states is supplied by a photon interaction. These higher states will decay to the ground state releasing the energy as a photon.

Comment: Actually, the square of the wave function gives you the _probability density_ at a specific (x,y,z). $ψ^2 (x,y,z)$ needs to be integrated over a space interval to give the actual _probability_ of finding the electron in that area of space. The probability of finding the electron in a specific location (x,y,z) is actually zero.

Comment: Thanks Anna v for enlighten me but you didn't got my actual  question. I accidently gave the topic as Bohr model. I wrote orbitals and I mean that they are orbitals and I am not taking about orbits. Ok. I actually mean that why they are stationary? If it is just equations told that then why equations told that there is and energy cloud called orbitals? What helps that energy to stay there and from where it come from?

Comment: equations do not tell that there is an energy cloud. Equations tell us that there exist energy levels fitted/modeled with the wavefunction. The energy operator operating on the wave function will give the energy of that level.

Comment: systems tend to the ground state, by radiating away http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/201674/could-it-be-that-all-energy-is-seeking-ground/201684#201684 . The cloud image is a representation of the probability density to find an electron at (x,y,z) when measuring it. Not an energy cloud, a probabilistic energy cloud.

Comment: can you please explain me in detail the word you used as energy operator.

Comment: As you said it is a probabilistic energy cloud then here electron will have same energy( not taking about excited state) agree and as it is a energy cloud there will be energy( you will also agree this). Then why is this energy cloud always remain in that form for all the time? Why don't they turn into mass or other forms of energy. I am not at all taking about excited states.

Comment: Physics ultimately does not answer why. why end up on the postulates of quantum mechanics which were chosen so that the observed behavior is fitted. The answer then is "because that is the way nature behaves and is well modeled by QM"

Answer (score 0):

Taking your questions in this order:

> As it is said energy tangled with mass and vice versa.

Energy tangled with mass is the equation E = mc$^2$, meaning, as I am sure you know, energy and  mass can convert into each other using this equation. For your particular question though, I would ask you to (temporarily) forget this idea as, although you are correct, it really has nothing to do with the rest of your question and it is only confusing things.

> What is the idea of stationary orbital of electron? From where does this energy come from?

In nature, if an object has a chance to lose energy, it **will** lose that energy, like you holding a rock above the ground and then dropping it.  The potential energy of the rock will vanish when it lies on the ground and you will need to use your own energy to pick it back up.

In something like the same way, if an electron and a proton get close enough, because they have opposite electric charges, they will be attracted to each other and form an atom, in this case the Hydrogen atom.

As the electron is pulled into towards the proton, it will emit radiation (and lose energy doing that ) until it goes into the lowest orbit around the proton, (which is called the 1 S orbital), in which it will have the lowest energy level. Unless it receives energy from say, a light photon, it will stay in that orbit forever, that is your reference to "stationary", as it does not have enough energy to go anywhere.

The electron will not go straight "into" the proton, otherwise we would not have atoms, instead it will most likely be found somewhere around the proton, in an orbital region.  We can't say "exactly" where it will be found, we can only say where there is a very high chance it will be found.

> how is this energy always be in the form of cloud such as s, p, d, f.

The electrons that gather around the nucleus of an atom have to follow a set of rules, which we just accept as we don't fully understand them.  One of these rules says that only two electrons can be at the lowest energy level and that any other electrons must go into higher energy levels, as the one below them is full.

As the next electrons come along, they have more energy and they arrange themselves in the p, d, f orbitals according to the rule I said above, that only two electrons can fit into each orbital. But the crucial part to remember here is that the 2nd highest energy level allows the electrons to have more energy than the lowest energy level,  so the electrons take up different orbital patterns, not just spherical like the 1 S orbital, but other odd shapes such as the p, d and f orbitals, that allow them to do three things at once:

- All have the same energy.
- All obey the rule that only two electrons can fit into each orbital.
- All stay as far apart as they can from each other, as they are all negatively charged so will "push" away from each other as much as possible while still staying at the same energy.

As anna says, don't think of the energy being in a cloud, it's not anything directly to do with energy, instead think of the cloud as the region where the electron is most likely to be found.

[image]

That is the most straightforward answer I can give you.  In this answer, I need to ignore or simplify a lot of points, so my apologies for doing that.

anna has given you a much better answer than mine, although you might need to read more about this subject first to follow it.

Comment: how can one tell that this (pointing to any thing) has a chance to loss energy? As you say that "electron will stay in that orbit forever" my question is why it will forever be in that orbit only( don't consider excited states)? Why don't the energy cloud vanish away or what is stopping it to not vanish away?

Comment: I don't honestly think anybody could answer that except to say it would contradict the conservation of energy law. As far as we know, energy and mass can't just disappear, if it did you and I would not be here.  I don't want to avoid your question, or offend you in any way, but it's just a rule of nature, the same as saying, on a bigger scale, why does a cricket ball not just suddenly vanish?

Comment: Now you perfectly got my question. What is stopping that energy not to move to a lower energy state?

Comment: Ok, these facts are hopefully obvious to both of us: we need atoms to exist, the atoms are made from electrons and protons, the electrons are in orbitals and there must be a lowest energy orbital otherwise no atom would be stable and then we would not be here. The electron has nowhere else to go and it can't go "poof" and vanish, because of energy mass conservation, so it's going to stay where it is.  It's as much logic as it is physics, if you accept atoms as building blocks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate energy mass conservation point with respect to my question. All you said is theoretically correct and proved. Do you have any other explanation? I am still confused. In my perspective there would be something between the nodes and antinode which is constantly giving energy to the orbitals so that they be in a fixed energy state so that law of energy mass conservation occur. My question is sounding like a silly question still I am not satisfied with all the answer. I my be wrong in my perspective.

Comment: Hi Nukul, your persistence is to be admired, seriously. I mean absolutely no offence to you, but I do honestly think you are wrong in your perspective in this case, but I have lost count of the number of times I myself have been wrong in my perspective of the quantum world. I am sorry to say I cannot add more to what I have written already.

Comment: Ok I thought that I may be wrong. But you see I am still not able to figure out. Does atoms already exits or something after which it was made (are they made after big bang?). If they are already made then there has to be a thing or interactions which is helping the orbitals energy to be same for all time? Or if the atoms are made then orbitals are also make in sense of energy then what make these orbitals?