# Bohr' Atomic Model and Electrodynamics Confusion

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms

In my book,it says "According to laws of electrodynamics and maxwell's equations of electromagnetism,an electron orbiting the nucleus will slowly start radiating energy and would end up crashing spirally to the nucleus.This is the drawback of Rutherford's atomic model."

Then it gives the postulates about Bohr's atomic model where Bohr says that electron revolve around Nucleus in fixed orbits when they have neither released nor absorbed any energy.But doesn't it violate the previously said electrodynamics thing?

I am a newbie to this and not familiar with electrodynamics or maxwell's equations of electromagnetism,but how does bohr's atomic model solve the problem or energy radiation while an electron is revolving?

Comment: It didn't. He just assumed it away. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137207/520

Answer (score 0):

> But doesn't it violate the previously said electrodynamics thing?

Quantum mechanics had to be invented/developed because there were measurements/data in the laboratories that violated classical mechanics, classical electrodynamics and thermodynamics.

The Bohr model was the first step in explaining the atomic spectra, which showed distinct lines instead of a continuum of radiation 
when they atoms were excited and relaxed.

Then the Schrodinger equation provided a mathematically strict solution for the series describing the spectra, with a number of [postulates](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) in the interpretation of these solutions, and Quantum Mechanics was born.

It has been shown that the classical formulations emerge smoothly from the underlying quantum mechanical ones for the appropriate values of the variables involved .