# Frequency of Electromagnetic Radiations/Waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation

"A charge that is accelerated will produce variable electric
and magnetic fields. These are electromagnetic waves.
If the charge oscillates with a frequency f, then the
resulting EM wave will have a frequency f. If the charge
ceases to oscillate, then the EM wave is a pulse."

That is what i read but in some cases charges do not oscillate, they just accelerate but yet its said that they produce the electromagnetic waves of some frequency ?

Is the concept of frequency also applied to non oscillating waves ? What would be the cycle of those waves which are just variable but not oscillating ?

Comment: Consider a pulse, made up of various frequencies.

Comment: Related question: [How and why does accelerating charges radiate electromagnetic radiation?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65339/how-and-why-does-accelerating-charges-radiate-electromagnetic-radiation), additionally, see [Feynman's Lectures](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_28.html) for a corresponding derivation. To address the second part: the concept of frequency can be applied to any function as every function can be described by a combination of them, see [Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform).

Comment: so every function has a frequency ? what if a function is the combination of different frequencies ? what would be the frequency of that function then ?

Comment: so by doing a fourier analysis we can find the fundamental frequency of any wave and that fundamental frequency will be ragarded as the frequency of that wave/function ? am i right ?