# Why do accelerated charges radiate energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, charge, radiation, classical-electrodynamics

I have studied the statement that accelerated charges radiate energy and Bohr rectified this issue by introducing concept of stationary states or orbits.
But can anyone please tell me why does accelerated charges radiate energy???

Comment: have a look https://www.cv.nrao.edu/course/astr534/PDFnewfiles/LarmorRad.pdf

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/311114/46708