# Can inhomogeneity in the medium accelerate particles

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics, solitons

Suppose I have a charge which is moving in through a medium with constant velocity. Now, what will happen to the charge as it encounters an inhomogeneity in density? whether it will accelerate or decelerate, how to calculate the rate of acceleration or deceleration. All these are meant only in non relativistic regime.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/349349/how-is-the-energy-loss-by-an-accelerating-charge-expressed-in-the-equations-of-m