# Why alternating current produces electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, electric-current, acceleration, charge

So my question is: why alternating current produces electromagnetic waves?

There are plenty of answers on google that state it as fact, but none answer why. I  mean what is it about accelerating electrons that generate EM wave? Are the theories for it? Is there lazy explanation?

Comment: There are mathematical theories called quantum mechanical theories for electrons etc, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics  of how electrons emit the photons that build up light.

Comment: @annav Thank you so much! I will definitely read it. I wonder if I can avoid thinking about light since it behave both as particle and wave. Is is possible to think about EM purely in terms of waves and not particles?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How and why do accelerating charges radiate electromagnetic radiation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65339/)

Comment: There is classical electromagnetic theory, maxwells equations, that models the  wave nture  of light. Light emerges from the underlying quantum mechanical framework of photons, elementary particles with a quantum mechanical wave function which gives probabilities  of locating the photons. Look here to see how the classical wave interference emerges from summing single photons. https://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/

Comment: the explanation in the main answer of the proposed duplicate is in the classical electrodynamics frame work : "charges" not electrons, which are in the quantum regime.