# Direction of electromagnetic waves

Tags: electromagnetism

I took only the introductory electromagnetic course but I couldn't figured out when a single electron accelerated in vacuum which direction it emits electromagnetic waves and is the direction of motion of electron changes, assuming the electric field is along x axis and +x direction. For this question you should only consider the classical case I don't have Quantum electrodynamics background and I'm wondering how classical electrodynamics answers it. If there is a visual representation or an introductory book advise that explains my question I will be thankful for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Accelerating charge emits electromagnetic waves in ALL directions. That's why there exists Larmor formula of charge emitted power change over solid angle $\Omega$ : $$ {\frac {dP}{d\Omega }}={\frac {q^{2}}{4\pi c}}{\frac {\sin ^{2}(\theta )\,a^{2}}{c^{2}}} $$ But you can try to calculate direction of maximum power - according to extreme finding rules - assign equation to zero, and solve for $\theta$ .

Comment: Also take a look at [how and why do accelerating charges radiate electromagnetic radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65339/how-and-why-do-accelerating-charges-radiate-electromagnetic-radiation) question, which may help you.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas  thanks for your answer.