# Is there a fundamental relationship between Coulomb's law and Newton's Law of Gravitation?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, coulombs-law

It seems like the two equations are identical indicates that there is something more going on that unites them both, maybe in a cool way or something. Why are these two laws so similar?

Comment: They are only similar because the low energy, long range form of both interactions, when formulated as a classical field for basically static charges, is the same. For gravity that's structurally 100% false, already, because gravity is not a classical force, even though it can be fudged into the mathematical form of a force. In case of electrodynamics it's a pretty good approximation for heavy static charges. Moving charges and electrons, of course, do not obey a Coulomb law, at all, but we have to use the full equations of electrodynamics and quantum mechanics on them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Similarity between the Coulomb force and Newton's gravitational force](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54942/)

Comment: Apparently, this was a question that drove Einstein insane because he couldn't figure it out. Or at least that's what I've heard.

Comment: @Me2: Where did you hear that? Einstein couldn't have cared less about the Coulomb potential, which does not even meet the requirements of special relativity, let alone general relativity.

Answer (score -5):

### Motion

**The fundamental relationship between Coloumb's law and Newton's Law of Gravitation is Motion.**
To explain let us first take Einstein's E=MC2.

Now we know that anything times one is itself. Therefore when mass is 1, E=the speed of light squared. Therefore we can see that each piece of mass is the storage of the speed of light squared.

Now in geometry we know that a plane is created when applying a square value. This two-dimensional surface is the representation of space time. For example motion in a single direction moves only on a [one-dimensional surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-dimensional_space).

When the motion is squared the surface becomes a [two-dimensional surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_space).

Now if we wanted to represent each mass(1) as a spaghetti noodle holding the storage of the speed of light squared. You can picture the universe being made of what could be interpreted as a flying spaghetti monster.

So lets look a little deeper at a metaphorical spaghetti noodle. [Visible Light is electromagnetic radiation within a certain portion of the electromagnetic spectrum.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light) Therefore we can conclude that Mass is electromagnetic by nature of its existence.

**Electromagnetism**
[The electromagnetic force usually shows electromagnetic fields, such as electric fields, magnetic fields and light.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetism)

**Fundamental Interactions**
[There are four conventionally accepted fundamental interactions—gravitational, electromagnetic, strong nuclear, and weak nuclear—each understood as the dynamics of a field.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_interaction)

However we can logically conclude that since each fundamental interaction

- gravitational
- electromagnetic
- strong nuclear
- and weak nuclear

All have to do with Matter that both gravitational interactions and electromagnetic interactions are interactions involving the fields of the speed of light squared.

Now picture Lord Existence as a calm surface of water. If I tossed a stone into the water the waves vibrate out from the center of that interaction. Now picture a million little tiny stones being tossed into the water. All of these waves interact with each other creating an amazing network of tiny vibrations that vibrate at a much faster rate then the wave length of the single stone.

The [vibrational frequency of Matter is in the trillions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_vibrations). And the density of these vibrational fields determine the [state of matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_matter). Now we know that solid matter is formed by the grouping of these waves through the form of an [atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom). And at the root of the atom we find the [quantum fluctuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation) that gives detail to the formation of the speed of light squared.

**The Positive and the Negative Values**
Picture a sheet on a bed and a hand grasping the center of the sheet and making a fist bundling the sheet in the center of the hand. "Great Attraction" pulls together a positive value, and the negative space is then formed. Interestingly to me I found a similarity of this design in pictures of galaxies. Although the galaxies got a bit of a twist eh ^^,

Anyways, the very nature of this positive and negative value of space time is going to explain the Laws of Motion, the formation of matter, the reason for gravity, and also Coloumb's Law.

Now logically if the "Amazing Attraction" lets go of its positive value the negative value pulls space time back to its original position like [hydrostatic equilibrium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatic_equilibrium).

Now since "Fluctuating Attraction" causes this [Quantum Fluctuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation) resulting in the speed of light squared. The wave layer meaning the "Subatomic Vibrational Foundation" allows "All Matter" to form "Within Existence" in the "Active Plane" of "Now".

To make this easier to comprehend, let us see the objects of Existence as breathing.

**A magnet for example:**
As the object inhales the wave layer, this creates a negative [pole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_pole). As the object exhales the wave layer, this creates a positive [pole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_pole).

**Coloumb's Law**
Using the magnet as an example we know that two positive poles reject. This is because the to objects are exhaling against each other, increasing pressure from the objects. The same for the negative poles, for since both poles are inhaling, outer pressure builds between the two poles from the wave layer. This motion uses the law: the opposite and equal reaction.

**Newtons Law of Gravitation**
Although magnets breath from the wave layer more then many other objects (as proven by its magnetic poles). Objects in general also breath from the wave layer (otherwise they do not exist for the lack of quantum fluctuations). Although because of the amount of breathing, its force is much less. The mass itself (being a storage of the wave layer) grows in intensity as the objects become closer.

**The Proportions between the Two**
The wave layer is the wave layer, and the properties of itself is the same as itself. Therefore how Coloumb's Law interacts with the wave layer, is similar in nature to how Newton's Law of Gravitation interacts with the wave layer. And in both interactions the forces caused by the opposite and equal reactions gives the two Laws there defining attributes. Hooray for all power omnipresent Motion. The Lord who writes the Laws of Existence.