# Similarity in the formula of gravitational force and electrostatic force

Tags: electrostatics, newtonian-gravity

The gravitational force between two masses is given by: $$\vec{F_g}=G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$$
and the electrostatic force between two charged particles by:
$$\vec{F_e}=k\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}$$

Both the forces have inverse square dependence on the separation or distance although the two types of forces are totally
different. One can definitely ask if both charge and mass are totally different properties of matter, why does the force generated by them have such similar formulas?

---

My question might seem similar to [Similarity between the Coulomb force and Newton's gravitational force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54942/similarity-between-the-coulomb-force-and-newtons-gravitational-force). But that question is more specific if moving masses would generate some kind of field.

My question is, is the similarity in their formula just a coincidence or can we conclude something from it?

Comment: This question on why many forces are inverse square laws, is related. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47084

Comment: As CDCM pointed out: This is a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are so many forces explainable using inverse squares when space is three dimensional?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47084/)