# Gravitoelectromagnetism: How far does the analogy go?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gravity, linearized-theory

In weak gravitaional fields, we can write equations analogous to the Maxwell equations: [Gravitoelectromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism).

1. Do the gravitoelectric field and the gravitomagnetic field transform like components of a second rank tensor (2-form, to be exact) analogous to the Faraday tensor?

If so,

2. Does this tensor have some immediate relation to the Riemann/Ricci/Einstein tensors?
3. Can we use it to write the Einstein-Hilbert action in Yang-Mills form in this approximation?

Comment: Check this thesis on arxiv, you'll get your answers.
Gravitoelectromagnetism: Basic principles, novel approaches and their application to Electromagnetism

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75006/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, Gravitoelectromagnetism rank 2 tensor is like the electromagnetic tensor $F_{\mu\nu}$
2. I'm not aware of any relation. The tensors you listed depend on 2nd derivatives of the gravitational potential $g_{\mu\nu}$ while the gravitoelectromagnetic tensor depends on 1st derivatives.
3. Yes, you can use gravitoelectromagnetism to approximate gravity in qft. I don't think you should use the EH action rather the maxwell lagrangian for gravitoelectromagnetism.