# Analogue for $E$ and $H$ in mechanics

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, poynting-vector

I'm playing with mechanical analogues for current/voltage (force/velocity) and passive elements $RLC$ (damper, spring, mass). In order to define and analogue for Poynting vector... what should be the analogue for electric field $E$ and magnetic field $H$ in mechanics?

Comment: Well, there's [GEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism).

Comment: thank you, I found more information in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128650/

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_equivalence#Overview) [+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_equivalence#Examples) you can find a comparison between mechanics and electricity, and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Equivalent_systems) you can find a comparison between mechanical and electrical EDOs (could be useful also a [comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_circuit#Hopkinson's_law:_the_magnetic_analogy_to_Ohm's_law) between electrical and magnetical circuits)...(sorry need more space)

Comment: ...I don't know if you can make a perfect analogy but as I read the [Poynting's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting's_theorem) uses the Poynting vector to declare the conservation of the electromagnetic energy so I suppose the closest equivalent would just be the classical conservation of energy.